# How to get targetSdkVersion on runtime using Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I have Cordova application, in config.xml I specified targetSdkVersion:

How to read targetSdkVersion setting at runtime using Javascript in Cordova app?

Comment: maybe the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customconfigparameters can do the trick